# How to get Count value of content items by input field in orchard?

Tags: orchardcms

I have a custom Content Type "News" with custom field "Author" (Input Field),I would like to display statistics like this:
1."Peter" : 20post; 2."Linda" : 15post; 3."Mary"  : 10post; ....

How to get Count value of content items and sort by "Author" (Input Field)?
Thanks!

Comment: Best option is to have a taxonomy "Author" with terms "Peter, Linda..." and attach it to content type. Then, Orchard supports count per term.

Comment: A few years ago I've [written a module](https://github.com/Devqon/Devq.ExtendedBlog) for something similar to this. Checkout this module and just copy/paste what you need. It displays all items of a specific user, where you can of course also just display the number of items.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I can't use taxonomy terms, I don't know Author's name.

Comment: I try Devq.ExtendedBlog by devqon.I have orchard 1.7.3,First,I installed Contrib.Profile module ,then, Devq.ExtendedBlog,but nothing  in content type and content part,please help me  .I'm new in orchard ,Thanks!

Comment: HI,Devqon
I have some problems to help.
1.I installed Contrib.Profile module and Devq.ExtendedBlog in orchard 1.10.1,Add "Author" content part
in my content type(Authors).
2.To choose "Display Name" is active and Author Settings: Maximum number of tags is 0 ,
Display type of the items:summary in "Author".
3.then,In Queries ,
filter "Authors",
Sort Criteria by Publication date.
4.Last,Projection this Queries.

Comment: but ,except diplaying summary,No diplaying Maximum number of tags with the author.after I pushed 10 content items with "Display Name":Peter.
I'm confused，I'm new in orchard. please help me ,thanks!